# Elite\Elitist model in a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

When is the right time to use the Elite\Elitist mode in a Genetic Algorithm? I have no idea when to use it. What kind problems can be solved using this?

All I know is an elitist model is where you choose the elite (the solution with highest fitness function) and they have a reserve slot for the next generation, and they are the one up for crossover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much always use some form of elitism. What varies is the percentage (p) of best performers that you allow to survive to the next generation. So no elitism is basically saying p=0.

The higher p, the more your algorithm will have a tendency to find local peaks of fitness. i.e. once it finds a chromosome with a good fitness, it'll tend to focus more on optimizing it than trying to find new completely different solutions. On the contrary, if it's smaller, your GA will look for possible solutions all over the place and won't zero in as fast once it finds something close to the optimum solution.

So setting p correctly is going to have a direct impact on your algorithm's performance. But it depends on what you're after and your problem space. Play around with it a bit to adjust properly. I typically use 20% for the problems I work with, to give enough room for innovation. It works ok for me.